# Python : using data with both index and attributes

Tags: python

The code below was developed by many hours of trial and error as documentation does not seem to cover this.  How can this be made to allow any number of data sets as data is read from a file?

```
class data_array:
    def __init__(self):
    # initiates empty lists for each attribute
        self.number = []
        self.code = []
        self.connected = []
        self.reading = [] 
        self.location = []
        self.info_one = []
        self.info_two = []

sensor = [None] * 16

for ind in range(0, 16,1):
#  initiate the attributes
    sensor[ind] = data_array()
for ind in range(0,16,1):
# for loop to simulate reading data from a file
    sensor[ind].number = ind +1
    sensor[ind].code = "code" + str(ind +1)
    sensor[ind].connected =  False
    sensor[ind].reading = 201 + ind
    sensor[ind].location = "  where I found " + str(ind+1)
    sensor[ind].info_one = "  infor_one for sensor " + str(ind+1)
    sensor[ind].info_two = "  infor_two for sensor " + str(ind+1)

for ind in range(0,16,1):
# check data is accessable as intended
    print(sensor[ind].number, sensor[ind].code, 
    sensor[ind].connected, sensor[ind].reading, sensor[ind].location,
    sensor[ind].info_one, sensor[ind].info_two)
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Your code is... odd.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to open a file, and then read and process the file line by line.

```
fd = open("foo.txt", "r")  # Open file for read only

for line in fd:
    #  Do something  (I usually split the line into fields)
    f = line.strip().split(',')  # comma delimited values, strip LF

    if f[0] == 'Foo':
        fooval = f[1]  # Found a Foo, assign the value
        # Do something with fooval

fd.close()
```

This assumes the file contents looks something like this:

```
Foo,20
Foo,30
Bar,55
```

The size of the file is limited by system resources.

Lots more info on Python files here
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

If it were my code, I would probably create an object out of the values in data_array to keep them all together.

Comment: This probably doesn't answer the question,  because I wasn't sure what the question was.   However,  if you want to store "unlimited" data (not sure what the final size will be)  then put each chunk of data in a list and append that list to another list so you have a list of lists.  So easy in Python.  A little harder in C (using malloc etc)